# Generate random number that is not in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hope I can explain well.

So I have 8 boxes with class .boxA with a numeric value generated from js:

```
<div class="tfooter">
    <div class="boxA" id="bx3" value="3">3</div>
    <div class="boxA" id="bx27" value="27">27</div>
    <div class="boxA" id="bx46" value="46">46</div>
    <div class="boxA" id="bx40" value="40">40</div>
    <div class="boxA" id="bx42" value="42">42</div>
    <div class="boxA" id="bx29" value="29">29</div>
    <div class="boxA" id="bx13" value="13">13</div>
    <div class="boxA" id="bx1" value="1">1</div>
</div>
```

First of all I push all values in a array:

```
var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*50);
var array = [];
$(".boxA").each(function(){
    var dNumber = $(this).attr('value');
    array.push(dNumber);
});
```

Each of this boxes contain a random number from 1 to 50.

Now, I want to generate another random number and check if exists in the array. If exists, generate another number until it's unique in that array. When is unique, create another div.

I've tryed with indexOf, with inArray, with while, but I can't get it working. The problem is that generate. Generate new number until not in array.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Share the relevant HTML too.

Comment: Done, added html.

Comment: Now, I want to generate another random number and check if exists in the array. If exists, generate another number until it's unique in that array. When is unique, create another div. this is very inefficient as the array size increases, the hits would be harder to get

Comment: I tryed a while like this, but it seems i'm not that good at while's: 
 while (array.indexOf(randomnumber) == -1) {
                        $('.element_drag').attr('value',randomnumber);
                    }

Comment: @marvel308 i will delete divs so it will always be maxim 8. This was just for example only. I just need to check that array that will always have maximum 8 values, and add a unique random number.

Comment: Consider a different approach: at the very start generate an array of all possible numbers (0 to 49), and shuffle it randomly. Keep that array in memory. When a `div` has to be added, just take the next value from that array.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the trial-and-error method by first building an array with the *allowed* values (i.e. those that do not appear in the list), and then pick a random value from that.

Here is a snippet that will add a new (non-used) number at the top of the list at the press of a button:

```js
function getUsedNumbers() {
    return $(".boxA").map(function(){
        return +$(this).attr('value');
    }).get();
}

function getCandidates(exclude) {
    // Generate a list of values from 0 to 49, and make it a Set
    //   (Sets allow for faster look-up and value removal)
    var candidates = new Set(Array(50).keys());
    for (value of exclude) {
        // Remove the already used value from our Set: 
        candidates.delete(value);
    }
    // Convert Set back to array and return it:
    return [...candidates];
}

function pickRandomly(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
}

$('#add').click(function () {
    var used = getUsedNumbers();
    var candidates = getCandidates(used);
    // Safety:
    if (!candidates.length) {
        alert('No more candidate values available');
        return;
    }
    var choice = pickRandomly(candidates);
    // Insert the selected number at the top of the list:
    $(".tfooter").prepend(
        $("<div>").addClass("boxA").text(choice).attr({
            id: "bx"+choice, value: choice
        })
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div class="tfooter">
</div>
```

If you do this repeatedly, then it is not so efficient to re-read the list of values from the page each time, since you actually know what is there already.

Consider making the `candidates` `Set` the master reference for your data, and only depend on that to generate the output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to check if the random number exists in an existing array or not. if the number doesn't exist, it adds that random number to the array. Below is an updated code:

```js
$("#generateNewNumber").on('click', function() {
  var newArray = [];
  $(".boxA").each(function() {
    newArray.push(parseInt($(this).attr('value')));
  });

  var randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 50);
  console.log('Random number is: ' + randomNumber);
  if ($.inArray(randomNumber, newArray) !== -1) {
    console.log(randomNumber + ' exisits in array');
  } else {
    newArray.push(parseInt(randomNumber));
    $(".tfooter").append('<div class="boxA" id="bx' + randomNumber + '" value="' + randomNumber + '">' + randomNumber + '</div>')
    console.log(randomNumber + " doesn't exisits in array, hence adding in an array.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="generateNewNumber">Generate Random Number</button>
<div class="tfooter">
  <div class="boxA" id="bx3" value="3">3</div>
  <div class="boxA" id="bx27" value="27">27</div>
  <div class="boxA" id="bx46" value="46">46</div>
  <div class="boxA" id="bx40" value="40">40</div>
  <div class="boxA" id="bx42" value="42">42</div>
  <div class="boxA" id="bx29" value="29">29</div>
  <div class="boxA" id="bx13" value="13">13</div>
  <div class="boxA" id="bx1" value="1">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would had set up the code:

1. Create the array with numbers 1-50 in it.
2. Create a random number based on the list's length.
3. Randomly splice a position. That position will then be removed from the array but return a an array with one item.
4. If the array is empty (length 0), start over at 1.

Then you don't need to check if the number exists, because it has already been removed from the array.

```
function createBoxNumbersArray(startNumber, endNumber) {
  var boxNumbers = [];

  for (var i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; i++) {
    boxNumbers.push(i);
  }

  return boxNumbers;
}

function getRandom(boxNumbers) {
  position = Math.floor((Math.random() * boxNumbers.length-1));

  return boxNumbers.splice(position, 1)[0];
}
```

var boxNumbers = createBoxNumbersArray(1, 50);

var randomBoxNumber = getRandom(boxNumbers);

Answer (score 0):

Seems like indexOf would be the way to go. Your problem is that you're probably comparing the HTML attribute value (a string) to the random number (a number).

so, once you update to:

```
  array.push(parseInt(dNumber));
```

You will be able to check

```
  if(array.indexOf(randomnumber) >= 0) { } // regenerate random
```